# BitConverter.ToUint16 giving incorrect value?

Tags: c#, binary

My code is designed to extract the two middle bytes in a 4-byte message, then append the two middle bytes to form a 16 bit unsigned integer. Unfortunately I'm having problems with BitConverter.ToUint16 - my code doesn't seem to work correctly with it.

I've attached an image of the code and the relevant local variables below.

In this particular example, the central bytes are '10' and '152' in decimal. In binary, these are 00001010 and 10011000. That means the uint16 (numberIn) should be the decimal representation of 0000101010011000, which is 2712. Unfortunately the value the program finds is 38922.

What's going on?!

[image: code & local vars]

Comment: 38922 is binary 1001100000001010. Compare that with your "expected" value. Do you notice anything? Now go and read the [wikipedia article on endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET uses [little endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) so `00001010 10011000` is 38922. (`00001010b +  10011000b * 256`)

Comment: Thanks - I have fixed this problem now using the funciton described [here](http://www.lastrayofhope.co.uk/2010/01/03/csharp-endian-swap/)